# How to switch between paypal recurring payments and subscriptions?

Tags: paypal

I am migrating paypal subscriptions from old working paypal account to a newly created one. We have a standard subscription form on a site similar to described [here](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_subscr_techview_outside).

The problem is once I switched subscriptions to a new account (by changing

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
```

to a new email on the form) subscriptions started to behave differently.

Once I subscribe I get a completely different email saying:

> You set up an automatic payment profile to Company Inc.

Instead of:

> Subscription Receipt for Product

My paypal payment history also says `Recurring Payment To` instead of `Subscription Creation To`, and subsciption ID is now in `I-XXXXXXXX` format instead of `S-XXXXXXXXX`.

What do I need to setup on the new paypal account to make it produce regular subscriptions again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's no longer possible. As of October 2010 (I *think*) PayPal will no longer create S-type subscriptions, and new accounts are creating 'recurring payments' (starting with I-) by default, regardless of whether or not they have been created via the `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` API call, or via the HTML form.